# How to extract adress lines from this python code

Tags: python

How to extract adress from code like this below?
I have code with few companies data like below.
How can I extract adress from each one of them?

```
# importing the libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

url = "https://www.nwctcoc.org/current_members_iframe.asp"

# Make a GET request to fetch the raw HTML content
html_content = requests.get(url).text

# Parse the html content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")
business_types = []
for bt in soup.find_all(string=re.compile("\Business Type:.*")):
  business_types.append(bt.text.replace('\r\n' and 'Business Type:', ' ').strip())
```

Below code with single company data. I tried to copy them with counting lines, but adress have 2 or 3 lines...

```
<b>YMCA Camp Mohawk</b><br/>

                   

                  Business Type: Non-Profit Organizations, Camps <br/>

                   P.O. Box 1209 <br/>

                   246 Great Hill Road, Cornwall <br/>

                   Litchfield, CT  06759 <br/>

                  Phone

                  

                  : 860-672-6655 <br/>

                   

                  Fax: 860-482-3878 <br/>

                   

                  Contact: Patrick Marchand <br/>

                   

                  Email: <a href="mailto:patrick@campmohawk.org">patrick@campmohawk.org</a> <br/>

                   

                  Website: <a href="http://www.campmohawk.org" target="_blank">www.campmohawk.org</a><br/>
<br/> <br/>
</p>
```

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [ask], and make sure your question has a [mre].

Comment: you are assigning a value to `address_line`  but then you are printing the undeclared variable `business_line` instead

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed structure e.g. the address always follows `Business Type` field and a `<br/>` tag and precedes `Phone` you could grab this with brittle regex:

```py
import re

target_string = '''
<b>YMCA Camp Mohawk</b><br/>

                   

                  Business Type: Non-Profit Organizations, Camps <br/>

                   P.O. Box 1209 <br/>

                   246 Great Hill Road, Cornwall <br/>

                   Litchfield, CT  06759 <br/>

                  Phone

                  

                  : 860-672-6655 <br/>
'''

# two groups enclosed in separate ( and ) bracket
result = re.search(r"Business Type.*<br/>((.|\n)*)Phone( |\n)*:", target_string)

# Extract match value of first capture group
print(result.group(1))
```

Output:

```py
'''

                   P.O. Box 1209 <br/>

                   246 Great Hill Road, Cornwall <br/>

                   Litchfield, CT  06759 <br/>

                  '''
```

(I have preserved the newline characters in the regex, but you should be stripping them before using regex to make this simpler) e.g.

```py
import re

target_string = '''
<b>YMCA Camp Mohawk</b><br/> Business Type: Non-Profit Organizations, Camps <br/> P.O. Box 1209 <br/> 246 Great Hill Road, Cornwall <br/> Litchfield, CT  06759 <br/> Phone: 860-672-6655 <br/>
'''

# two groups enclosed in separate ( and ) bracket
result = re.search(r"Business Type.*<br/>(.*)Phone:", target_string)

# Extract match value of first capture group
print(result.group(1))
```

In general it would be better to structure your data with an `Address` field so that it is easier and safer to parse.

Answer (score -1):

Im doing something wrong, I have "p_body" as list not string?
Im newbie sorry for trouble

```
# importing the libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

url = "https://www.nwctcoc.org/current_members_iframe.asp"

# Make a GET request to fetch the raw HTML content
html_content = requests.get(url).text

# Parse the html content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")
business_types = []
for bt in soup.find_all(sting=re.compile("\Business Type:.*")):
  business_types.append(bt.text.replace('\r\n' and 'Business Type:', ' ').strip())


p_body = soup.find('p')


# two groups enclosed in separate ( and ) bracket
result = re.search(r"Business Type.*<br/>(.*)Phone:", p_body)

# Extract match value of first capture group
print(result.group(1))
```

Comment: This is not an answer please update your original question to include this information.

Comment: This is not an answer this is an edit to the original question with clarifying information